# Public risk taxonomies/lists?

Tags: risk-management, risk

I'm trying to find publicly available lists of risks which I can use in my own risk identification processes. Maybe risk taxonomies or just risk lists. Can anyone share such links?

Comment: There is a great set of answers about how to generate risks that I think addresses your basic need: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/762

Comment: [Software Risk Taxonomy from the Software Engineering Institute](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/library/abstracts/reports/93tr006.cfm)

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for risks, look at risk registers from previous projects. Those should be more relevant and accurate to whatever you're working on in your company. If they don't exist, try to get other PMs who worked on similar projects to list a couple for you and email them to you.

Ultimately, risks are very domain specific; risks in web development are not at all like risks in construction. So I don't think a public list exists, and if it did, I don't know how generic it would be.

Comment: This question is about risk lists/sources, not methods of risk identification.

Comment: The purpose of asking about risks is to generate risks that apply to your project, isn't it? My point is that no generated list will apply 100% to you; you're better off with generation.

Answer (score 5):

The [Risk Management Toolkit](http://www.mitre.org/work/sepo/toolkits/risk/index.html) on the Mitre.org site is probably the best resource on the web for risk management. Look on the right under *Taxonomies*.

There's a smaller and useful list at the end of Tom Kendrick's "*[Identifying and Managing Project Risk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814413404)*".

But note that I agree with Ashes: you can use these for inspiration, but handle with care!